# 13.04 gnome problem with drag and drop and text selection

Tags: 13.04, gnome, drag-and-drop

I have an ubuntu 13.04 gnome 64 bits, but since a few days I am facing serious problem for doing simple drag an drop : in nautilus, in eclipse, in the browser. Also I can't manage to select text areas with the mouse (the only way I found is to double click on the first word, then expand selection with shift and arrows keys).

I noticed that often, after having started a drag n drop, it is cancelled though I did not release the left mouse !

It is as if for each simple mouse clic : two was done !

My graphic card is an ati radeon hd 4330, and I had installed the default purposed driver.

I don't know if I should give you results from some terminal commands, as I don't know which could be useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look [here](http://shantanucse.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/how-to-solve-drag-drop-problem-in.html), hope it helps you.

It worked for mee.

EDIT: It says, basically:

*In previous version of ubuntu we saw that for two overlapping window drag & drop operation can not done. Because when we click on an item for dragging window(where the file is) get focus and raise on the top of other window.*

*Now in newer version we can solve it by **disabling the option of Raise on click**
Open Compiz-config-settings-manager (ccsm is the command if you open it using console) and go to  general option > focus & Raise tab. Un-check Raise on click and Auto raise option*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.